# How can I have two script commands in one build process for Azure DevOps YAML build definitions?

Tags: build, azure-devops

(There's [controversy going on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404629), but this should be well-enough defined to ask the question.)

We find ourselves needing three script jobs in one build path (that is, one YAML (.yml) file). I tried:

```
Steps:
- script: step1 1>&2
# # Do this after other tasks such as building
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 'TEST/*/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release'
  displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
- script: step2 1>&2
- script: step3 1>&2
```

But the build upchucks when there's more than one `- script` under `steps`. Normally I'd just pile them into one script and all that, but I can't because there's a test job in the middle. How can I make this thing run?

I copy and pasted it back and it started working. It must have been a non-printable character in the file.

Comment: What do you mean "upchucks"? can you share your logs?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk: Some kind of syntax error in the yml file. The build never starts. I'm not at work right now.

Comment: Please share your whole pipeline (when you at work ), I didn't get any error in the above syntax.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk: Ugh. Nonprintable character.

Comment: Hi @Joshua,

`> EDIT: copy/paste back and it started working. Must have been a non-printable character in the file.`

Looks like, you have solved the problem, right? If so, could you please post an answer to share a summary about your solution? This may be very helpful to more people who are looking for a solution for the similar problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy/pasted the original script lines from a MSDN document. On adding the second script line I got a nonsense error out of the yml parser (that I didn't capture) with the location of the second script `-` indicator as the location of the error and part of the script line as the error body. I then copy/pasted into stackoverflow to ask the question.

On copy/paste back from stackoverflow the error no longer appears. The only reasonable explanation is there was a non-printable character that got picked up on the original copy/paste from msdn that got eaten in the subsequent steps.

Answer (score 0):

In the pipeline job, the scripts you set in script tasks will be packaged as the corresponding script files to run on the agent. The script file for each script task is independent, and the pipeline will not package all of the scripts into one script file.

> Normally I'd just pile them into one script and all that, but I can't because there's a test job in the middle.

In your case, you can try directly executing the '[**dotnet test**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test)' command in the script task instead of using the [**.NET Core CLI task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops).

With this way, you can write the scripts for '**`step1`**', '**`dotnet test`**', '**`step2`**' and '**`step3`**' into one script file, and execute this script file with only one script task in the pipeline.